# Two columns merge into one but merge creates again two

Tags: r

I have two dataframes:

```
df1 = data.frame(text = c("text1","text2"), id=c(1,2))
df2 = data.frame(text = c("text3","text4"), id=c(3,4))
```

I would like to create a new column from the two text columns
However using this it gives two columns

```
dftext <- merge(df1$text,df2$text)
```

Expected data output:

```
dftext
text1
text2
text3
text4
```

What is the correct option?

Comment: @RichScriven I updated the answer with the expected output

Answer (score 1):

You have plenty of options here, the easiest and most appropriate being `rbind()`.

```
rbind(df1["text"], df2["text"])
#    text
# 1 text1
# 2 text2
# 3 text3
# 4 text4
```

or

```
rbind(df1, df2)["text"]
#    text
# 1 text1
# 2 text2
# 3 text3
# 4 text4
```